# Replacement for glOrtho in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm in the process of moving from legacy OpenGL to modern OpenGL, but I need a replacement for glOrtho, as it is now removed. I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do some of the things done in C++ in Java due to the differences in the imports.

The relevant code: `GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), 0, Display.getWidth(), 100, -100);` 
This is the current ortho function I use, along with the old `glEnable`s that are now not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is `glOrtho (...)` is trivial to implement, you do not even need any trigonometric functions like you would for a perspective projection matrix.

You will want to construct an LWJGL `Matrix4f` as follows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC534299.png))</sub>
, given: [image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC534300.png))</sub>

Keep in mind that this matrix is column-major, so you would fill it like this:

```
Matrix4f.m00 = 2.0f/(right-left);
Matrix4f.m01 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m02 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m03 = 0.0f;

Matrix4f.m10 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m11 = 2.0f/(top-bottom);
Matrix4f.m12 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m13 = 0.0f;

Matrix4f.m20 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m21 = 0.0f;
Matrix4f.m22 = -2.0f/(far-near);
Matrix4f.m23 = 0.0f;

Matrix4f.m30 = -(right+left)/(right-left);
Matrix4f.m31 = -(top+bottom)/(top-bottom);
Matrix4f.m32 =   -(far+near)/(far-near);
Matrix4f.m33 = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Would I use this in the same spot as glOrtho? Or do I need to apply it every loop?

Comment: @KenzieTogami: You are moving to "modern" OpenGL, correct? What you would actually do with this is pass this matrix to a GLSL program matrix uniform. Modern OpenGL eliminated the "current" matrix stack, so there are no functions that multiply a current matrix, and you pass all of your matrices to shaders instead.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

If you want to use OpenGL in Java, I would recommend JOGL instead of LWJGL. Since LWJGL is supposed to be more of a "game engine". Below is some example code.

```
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, near_val, far_val);
    gl.glEnable(cap);
```

http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/

Comment: That really would not help a whole lot, the question is about moving from legacy OpenGL to modern OpenGL. `glOrtho (...)` will still be unavailable in modern OpenGL (3.2+ core) whether you use LWJGL or JOGL.